# Why can you add a user to a group with usermod, but you cant remove a user from a group with usermod?

Tags: command-line, permissions, users

Uhy can you add a user to a group with `usermod`, but you cant remove a user from a group with `usermod`? Am I wrong?

I got a user I want to remove from the `sudo` group. I put this user in with `usermod`, now I have to use `deluser` to remove the user from the group?

On a test box, I ran `sudo usermod -G "" user` (bad advice form some thread I read) which removed all the groups, glad I didn't run that on the server.

From the man page, I see a `-W` option that mentions removing a list of `gids`. Are `gids` groups?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting user from sudoers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605130/deleting-user-from-sudoers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a user from a group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80115/how-to-remove-a-user-from-a-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, you can in fact remove a user from a supplementary group with `usermod` - by passing a list of *groups to keep* to the `-G` command. From `man usermod`:

> ```
>    -G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
>        .
>        .
>        .
>
>        If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed,
>        the user will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be
>        changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current
>        supplementary group list.
> ```

Ex.

```
$ id testuser
uid=1001(testuser) gid=1001(testuser) groups=1001(testuser),27(sudo),33(www-data),100(users)

$ sudo usermod -G users,www-data testuser

$ id testuser
uid=1001(testuser) gid=1001(testuser) groups=1001(testuser),33(www-data),100(users)
```

Answer (score 3):

You *can* add and remove a user from a group using `usermod`. User `-a` to add a user to a group; and use `-r` to remove a user from a group. You can use `cat` on the `/etc/group` file to see the members of all groups:

```
sudo usermod -a -G <group> <username>
cat /etc/group | grep <group>
sudo usermod -r -G <group> <username>
cat /etc/group | grep <group>
```